Need Support for Configuring Permissions for Cloud Run via Crossplane to Resolve 'Error: Forbidden
When creating Cloud Run services using Crossplane, I encountered the error: "Error: Forbidden - Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server.
enter image description here
While I can resolve this issue manually via the GCP console by adjusting permissions,
enter image description here
After this, I'm able to access it successfully.
enter image description here
I would like to request a feature to handle these permissions directly through Crossplane configurations. This would streamline the process of managing Cloud Run services without requiring additional steps in the GCP console. Having this capability in Crossplane would significantly improve the user experience by ensuring all necessary permissions are handled declaratively.
This is the config I have right now to create a Cloud Run service.
apiVersion: cloudrun.gcp.upbound.io/v1beta1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.upbound.io/example-id: cloudrun/v1beta1/service
  labels:
    testing.upbound.io/example-name: cloudrun-service
  name: cloudrun-service
spec:
  providerConfigRef:
    name: providerconfig
  forProvider:
    location: us-central1
    template:
      - spec:
          - containers:
              - image: us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello
              
    traffic:
      - latestRevision: true
        percent: 100

This is the Provider detail
https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/upbound/provider-gcp-secretmanager/v1.8.3/resources/secretmanager.gcp.upbound.io/Secret/v1beta1#doc:spec-forProvider-annotations
https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/upbound/provider-gcp-secretmanager/v1.8.3/resources/secretmanager.gcp.upbound.io/Secret/v1beta1#doc:spec-forProvider-annotations

Considering there’s a workaround within Google Cloud Platform console in sorting the permission error, it would be best to file a feature request against Crossplane for this specific use case.
I noticed that you already reached out to them. Please continue monitoring the tickets for future updates. It may take some time implementing this depending on their priority:

crossplane

provider-upjet-gcp


You can also submit a request directly in provider-gcp repo.
